Automaticly move numbers from one text field to another (InDesign)
I'm currently working on a Greek New Testament and need to move all verse numbers out of the body text to another text field to the left that will be placed in the margin. The verse numbers need to be placed on the same row in the new text field.
Here is an image that illustrates what I need to do:

Is there any way to automate this process in InDesign?
I would really appreciate some help, an automatic solution in this case would save me weeks of additional work.

What happens if there are two numbers in one line?

Search and replace using a tab in one frame is not enough? Anyway the XML import framework can do this via a XSL style sheet and some creative tagging in the template. This is primarily meant for 2 column hanging headers, warning and comment blocks commonly used in technical writing.  But this is the same situation anyways. But haven't done this in 7 years so don't ask me to do it. But it is possible if you really want to have a XML workflow.

Is it not possible to have one text frame and use a number list? Using a minus First Line Indent matching the Left Indent will indent the text. Set it up in a paragraph style based on a body paragraph style to make life easier – you can then adjust the indents if you find you need more space later on.
[
